# How to prevent static method in base class from being overridden

Tags: c++, function, static, overriding

I have a base class `algorithmType` that holds member variables and functions that all algorithms (fifo, lru & optimal) have in common.

I have a static member variable in the base class called `row`. It is static because it must be the same for all of the algorithms.

I have other functions that are not static that I can just prefix with `virtual` (and append with `final` in C++11).

My dirty fix so far is to just create an object directly from the base class, without instantiating it, and using that to access the (now) non-static function that returns the static `row` member variable. The purpose of this is to allow me to easily tell if a derived class has a function with the same name as a function in the base class (it will produce an error). Anyone making a new derived class shouldnt accidentally name a function by a name that they might need from the base class.

The `final` keyword is very useful, but isn't allowed for static functions.

Any suggestions?

```
class B
{
 private:
 static int row;

 public:
 static int getRow()
 {
  return row;
 }
}

class D : B
{
 public:

 int num;
 int getRow() // I want an error when I try to declare this function, like "final" does.
 {
  return num;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: A method cannot be overridden if it is not virtual to begin with.

Comment: I think [this](http://pastebin.com/YYebzt4W) is what op wants.

Comment: Maybe put those static methods in a singleton of some helper class?

Comment: @A.S.H and declare the singleton 'final'

Comment: @Aminos that can't be bad though not sure if necessary.

Comment: If you think that somebody can accidentally name a function in a derived class, you need different language.

Comment: If that were the case, then why did they come out the "final" specifier? I just want to be sure that derived classes are not using the same function names as the ones in the base class. Is this something that I shouldn't be worried about? I would want this ability for any language I chose, C++ or not. Plus I like the freedom and flexibility that C++ offers.

Comment: "Is this something that I shouldn't be worried about?" Yes. There's no harm in a derived class defining a function with the same name as a function in the base class. It can complicate calling the base version, but that's not your problem to solve; that's a problem for whoever write the derived class.

Comment: I figured as much, but then why did they include the "final" keyword in the 2011 standard? "final" gives a compile error when you name a function in the derived class that already exists in the base. While the person writing the derived class should be aware of this, i just want to be able to catch all conflicts to the base class, whether they're static or virtual, not just virtual.